# Is there a way to change the url of audioplayer once the state is changed on the component it exists in?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working on an application that uses text to speech API services. On the front end, I have a textarea element that takes in the input value and a button that consequently makes a post call so that I get back the speech of the script I have written in form of an URL.
These are the state variables of the component

```
state = {
        textVal: "",
        audioUrl: "",
    }
```

This is the handleChange method, textarea, and the button HTML.

```
handleChange() {
    this.setState({ textVal: event.target.value });
}


<textarea
                        placeholder="Insert script here"
                        rows="4"
                        cols="50"
                        value={this.state.textVal}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />


<button onClick={this.audioRequest}>
                        Listen
</button>
```

This is how I make the post call, although I have removed unnecessary stuff

```
audioRequest() {
        const data = {
            textScript: this.state.textVal,
        };
        axios.post(
            "...", data)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                this.setState({
                    audioUrl: data.audioUrl,
                });
            });
    }
```

After this, I pass on the URL to the audio player element as shown with just a conditional to check if I URL isn't empty

```
<audio controls>
{(this.state.audioUrl === "") ? 
"Nothing to play yet" : 
<source src={this.state.audioUrl} type="audio/wav" />}
</audio>
```

The problem starts when I type in a new script and hit the listen button, I do get the new URL back in the console but the audio player does not play new the script, instead plays to the first one.

I would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the audio replay as well, like this:

```
        onClick={() => {
          setSource("/file_example_OOG_1MG.ogg");
          ref.current.pause();
          ref.current.load();
          ref.current.play();
        }}
```

Working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-audio-player-forked-wx225?file=/src/Player/Player.js